# How to Vectorize python function

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, vectorization

I have made a resume parser but to parse my resumes, I am using a for loop to run my parse function over each resume. Is there a way to vectorize this approach?
I tried to use `.apply()` function by putting my resumes in a Series but it doesn’t help in performance. Also, I have heard of pandas UDF for vectorization can help. Is that true? Below is my code.

```
start=time.time()
resume_list,resume_name=form_list()
final=[]
for resume in resume_list:
    final.append(extract_everything(resume))
final_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(final,index=resume_name)
print(f"{time.time()-start} seconds")
```

Comment: Have you a minimal example?

Comment: I cannot share the code since it is for a client but I'll just give an example, lets says resume_list=[] this is my list of resumes  with around thousands of resumes and I am running a for loop to iterate each resume and applying a function on each resume which returns me a dictionary with the required entities from resume.  start=time.time(). 
resume_list,resume_name=form_list()# converts resume to text. 
final=[]. 
for resume in resume_list:  
    final.append(extract_everything(resume))  
final_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(final,index=resume_name). 
print(f"{time.time()-start} seconds").

Comment: Please, put the example in your post

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the meaning of 'vectorize'.

Comment: multiprocessing could help you better in terms of performance.

Comment: okk I am sorry this is my first time using stack overflow

Comment: No problem. it is just that your issue will be more comprehensible if everything is in the post.

Comment: okk so any idea how can I improve the performance in this code now? https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06 I referred to this for vectorization

Comment: and this for pandas udf https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python-pandas.html

Comment: You should post a [mre].